# How do I format an email for Gmail?

Tags: email, codeigniter, formatting, gmail, html-email

I'm sending out an email using [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter)'s built in library.  All I'm trying to do is send a bolded string, but instead of rendering the tags, it is printing them.  What I have:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <b>Donkey</b>
 </body>
 </html>
```

That is, character for character, the email I'm getting.  Why aren't the tags rendering?

Comment: Does this only cause problems with Gmail? If you read the email in Outlook, or Yahoo! Mail, does it render correctly?

Comment: Probably has to do with the sending mime type...  check the codeigniter library's api for a way to toggle sending an html version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html):

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

The CodeIgniter Email class defaults to sending text emails.  Unless you specify that the mailtype is HTML (`$config['mailtype'] = 'html';`) your html will be sent out as text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<span style='font-weight: bold'>My bold text</span>
```

OR

```
<strong>another bold tag</strong>
```

?

We use these and they both work for Gmail.